# Accidently Erased ./etc/ directory:

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

I have accidently deleted the /etc/ directory. I believe it has all system files in it. I tried to fix it by rebooting the system, but it doesn't reboot, neither it detects OS installation media (Bootable USB).
[image: pic]

I would really appreciate if someone would help me with it.

[image: pic]

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way to recover from this situation is to restore the system from backups.

The second quickest way is to reinstall it from scratch (don't forget to secure your data, so you don't wipe it accidentally).

Consider using [Timeshift](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift) in the future. It's a neat tool that lets you rollback the system (*not data*) to a past version. It needs to be set up *before* an incident though.